# tableView reloadData not working: cellForRowAtIndexPath not called

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have this problem `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called by `reloadingData`. I have spent a lot of time with this. I xib file `dataSource` and `delegate` are connected to `File's Owner`. Any idea is welcome.

This is my code :

**cellForRowAtIndexPath********

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        cell.backgroundView.opaque = NO;
        //cell.alpha = 0.65;

        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.opaque = NO;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];

        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.opaque = NO;
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

        NSString *temp = [distanceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if([checkMarkArray count] != 0){
          NSString *checkString = [checkMarkArray objectAtIndex:0];
          NSLog(@" checkString %@",checkString);
          if ([temp isEqualToString:checkString ]) {
            cell.accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"]] autorelease];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"]] autorelease];
        }
        }

    }

    // Set up the cell...
    [[cell textLabel] setText: [distanceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ;
   return cell;
}
```

*didSelectRowAtIndexPath***********

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",cellText);
    [checkMarkArray removeAllObjects];

    if([[tableViewDistance cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {

        //global array to store selected object
        [checkMarkArray removeObject:[distanceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"array %@",checkMarkArray);
        [tableViewDistance cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"]] autorelease];

        [[tableViewDistance cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

          [self.tableViewDistance  reloadData];
    }
    else
    {
        [checkMarkArray addObject:[distanceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSLog(@"array again %@",checkMarkArray);

        [tableViewDistance cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"]] autorelease];

        [[tableViewDistance cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
          [self.tableViewDistance  reloadData];

    }
    tableViewDistance.delegate = self;
    tableViewDistance.dataSource = self;
    [self.tableViewDistance  reloadData];
}
```

****viewDidLoad********

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    distanceArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"20 Kilomètres", @"40 Kilomètres", @"60 Kilomètres",@"80 Kilomètres",nil];
    NSLog(@"distance %@",distanceArray);
    tableViewDistance.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    checkMarkArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Comment: what do you mean it does not reloadData, when? Since you have all your setup in viewDidLoad this all gets called only once (normally) anyway. Only ViewDidAppear or viewWillAppear get called multiple times. Did you modify the array somewhere? Could you please clarify?

Comment: I need to reload tableview after I select a row, because I need to be only one select row at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found some weak parts in your code:

1. You should set `cell.accessoryView` out of `if (cell == nil){}`
2. In `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you can use `tableView` and not use `tableViewDistance` (may be it is `nil`?)
3. In `- (void)viewDidLoad` you should call first `[super viewDidLoad];` and then make customizations.

Hope that will help you. Gl

Comment: Thanks a lot Nekto ..the problem was cell.accessoryView inside of if(cell==nil){}

Answer (score 1):

connect Your tableView outlet (UITableView *tableViewDistance) to Your Xib TableView.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

instead of

```
 [self.tableViewDistance  reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to the question, you want to have only one cell selected at a time, so you want to deselect the previously selected cell and select the one currently selected. You can use the `-indexPathForSelectedRow` method of `UITableView` to find the selected row:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // For multiselect, use an array to store the checked state instead of using the tableView's state.
  [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
  [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = ...;
}
```

You will also want to implement `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = ...;
}
```