# UITableview Reload issue iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

some times `reloadData` method of `UITableView` is not working i.e means when i wrote like `[tableView reloadData]` then sometimes it is calling the datasource methods and sometimes not.

what might be the problem is, can anyone please give me the answer.

Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation  {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.   
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){      
    [self performSelector:@selector(changeSegmentControllerFrame) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0001];        
    [m_kwikiTable reloadData];      
    return YES;     }   
    else        
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait); 
}
```

Comment: Posting your code will help to understand your Question & the code ...

Comment: please post some code...

Comment: here my problem is when i navigate to one view and came back to first view than my tableview Delegate methods are called but Datasource methods are not called

Comment: Where are you calling reload data besides shoudlAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation? In viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear?

Comment: when i change the orientation my table view should reload, so i am calling the reload method in shoudlAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation method only

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a breakpoint at

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

method... because if this returns zero then it will not bother executing the next method i.e.,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: tried by putting the break point "numberofrowsInSection" method is calling but - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath is not calling, didn't get what the problem is.

Comment: Is the number of rows returned greater than 0, when numberofrowsInSection is called?

Comment: "here my problem is when i navigate to one view and came back to first view than my tableview Delegate methods are called but Datasource methods are not called" - so, in viewWillAppear of the first view, set the delegate and datasource of the tableview, if it works,then you are nullifying the datasource somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your codes.Any way check these things in your codes.

1. You should set cell.accessoryView out of if (cell == nil){}
   2.In - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath you can use tableView and not use tableViewDistance (may be it is nil?)
   3.In - (void)viewDidLoad you should call first [super viewDidLoad]; and then make customizations.

Go through this link, this will help you to debug:

[tableView reloadData not working: cellForRowAtIndexPath not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528512/tableview-reloaddata-not-working-cellforrowatindexpath-not-called)

Answer (score 0):

put nslog in delegate

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

before returning row count to check if it is retuning 0 or any other value